# ReferenceError: cleanSearch is not defined

Tags: jquery

I am using the reveal jQuery plugin to create a modal on my web page:

I have added the scripts at the bottom of the page as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

I have the reveal plugin in plugins.js

and have created the following script to add the modal popups:

```
var ORC = ORC || {};

// Reveal Modal Popup
function modalPopup(linkID, modalID) {
    $(linkID).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(modalID).reveal({
            animation: 'none',
            animationspeed: 200,
            closeonbackgroundclick: false,
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
        return false;
    });
}

ORC.init = function () {
    //Ts&Cs
    modalPopup('#selectTerms', '#contentTerms');
    //Privacy
    modalPopup('#selectPrivacy', '#contentPrivacy');
};

$(ORC.init);
```

But I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: cleanSearch is not defined
```

When I click on the close link on the modal popup.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

**[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/zidski/pSBfw)**

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net?  Also provide a link to the plugin in question.

Comment: which file is this error originating from?

Comment: Are you sure you included *all* the plugins?

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/pSBfw/

Comment: In your HTML you have `<a href="#" class="close" onclick="return cleanSearch();">Close</a>`.  Why do you have `return cleanSearch();` there?  It seems to work if you just remove that.